# JQuery Submit button won't highlight on first click of Yes or No, how do I this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Once the user has entered a username and selected Yes or No the submit button should be highlighted...........................................................................................................

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_form()
        {
            if( ($( "input[name='username']" ).val().length > 0) &&
                ($( "input[name='car']:checked" ).length))
            {
                $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            else
            {
                $(":submit").attr("disabled",true);
            }
        }
        $( document ).ready(function() {
                $( "input[type='text'] " ).keyup( function() {
                        check_form();
                }); 
                $( "input[type='radio'] ").mouseup(function() {
                        check_form();
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="my_form" name="the_form">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" oninput="check_form();" />
        <br><br>
        Do you own a car?   Yes: <input type="radio" name="car" value="yes" />
                            No:  <input type="radio" name="car" value="no" />
        <br><br>
        <input type="reset" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" disabled />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<form id="my_form" name="the_form">
  Username:
  <input type="text" name="username" oninput="check_form();" />
  <br>
  <br> Do you own a car? Yes:
  <input type="radio" name="car" value="yes" /> No:
  <input type="radio" name="car" value="no" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="reset" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" disabled />    
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function check_form() {
  if (($("input[name='username']").val().length > 0) &&
    ($("input[name='car']:checked").length)) {
    $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $(":submit").attr("disabled", true);
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='text'] ").change(function() {
    check_form();
  });
  $("input[type='radio'] ").change(function() {
    check_form();
  });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tyhv09y9/)

Answer (score 0):

Use **change** instead of **mouseup**

```
$("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
    check_form();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. I'd used the `.change()` function instead

```
$('document').ready(function(){
            $('#my_form :input').change(function(){
              if( ($( "input[name='username']" ).val().length > 0) &&
                  ($( "input[name='car']:checked" ).length))
              {
                  $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
              }
              else
              {
                  $(":submit").attr("disabled",true);
              }
            });
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="my_form" name="the_form">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
        <br><br>
        Do you own a car?   Yes: <input type="radio" name="car" value="yes" />
                            No:  <input type="radio" name="car" value="no" />
        <br><br>
        <input type="reset" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" disabled />

</form>
```